# How can I print the entire converted sentence on a single line?

Tags: python, join, printing

I am trying to expand on Codeacademy's Pig Latin converter to practice basic programming concepts.

I believe I have the logic nearly right (I'm sure it's not as concise as it could be!) and now I am trying to output the converted Pig Latin sentence entered by the user on a single line.

If I print from inside the for loop it prints on new lines each time. If I print from outside it only prints the first word as it is not iterating through all the words.

Could you please advise where I am going wrong?

Many, many thanks for your help.

```
pyg = 'ay'

print ("Welcome to Matt's Pig Latin Converter!")

def convert(original):
    while True:
        if len(original) > 0 and (original.isalpha() or " " in original):
            print "You entered \"%s\"." % original
            split_list = original.split()

            for word in split_list:
                first = word[0]
                new_sentence = word[1:] + first + pyg
                final_sentence = "".join(new_sentence)
                print final_sentence


            break

        else:
            print ("That's not a valid input. Please try again.")
            return convert(raw_input("Please enter a word: "))

convert(raw_input("Please enter a word: "))
```

Comment: use `print` to display values in variables (and text like "I'm before 'for'") and see what is going on in program. Or learn how to use debuger.

Comment: add `,` at the end of `print` to print in one line `print final_sentence,`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pyg = 'ay'

print ("Welcome to Matt's Pig Latin Converter!")

def convert(original):
    while True:
        if len(original) > 0 and (original.isalpha() or " " in original):
            final_sentence = ""
            print "You entered \"%s\"." % original
            split_list = original.split()
            for word in split_list:
            first = word[0]
            new_sentence = word[1:] + first + pyg
            final_sentence = final_sentence.append(new_sentence)
            print final_sentence



            break

        else:
            print ("That's not a valid input. Please try again.")
            return convert(raw_input("Please enter a word: "))

convert(raw_input("Please enter a word: "))
```

It's because you are remaking final_sentence every time in the for loop instead of adding to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the program logic but a quick solution would be appending all the final_sentence in a list, and after the for print the list with a Join.

```
pyg = 'ay'

print ("Welcome to Matt's Pig Latin Converter!")

def convert(original):
    to_print = []
    while True:
        if len(original) > 0 and (original.isalpha() or " " in original):
            print "You entered \"%s\"." % original
            split_list = original.split()

            for word in split_list:
                first = word[0]
                new_sentence = word[1:] + first + pyg
                final_sentence = "".join(new_sentence)
                to_print.append(final_sentence)

            print " ".join(to_print)
            break

        else:
            print ("That's not a valid input. Please try again.")
            return convert(raw_input("Please enter a word: "))

convert(raw_input("Please enter a word: "))
```

This code does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
for word in split_list:
  first = word[0]
  new_sentence = word[1:] + first + pyg
  final_sentence = "".join(new_sentence)
  print final_sentence
```

You are joining a single word to itself.  You will want to save all the words from inside the loop, then print them once the loop are processed them all.

```
final = []
for word in split_list:
  new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + pyg
  final.append(new_word)

print ' '.join(final)
```

Or, just for fun, here's the one-liner:

```
print ' '.join([word[1:]+word[0]+'ay' for word in split_list])
```

***EDIT:***  Also, @furas makes a good point in their comment, to print with **no newline** simply add a `,` to the end of the print statement:

```
for word in split_list:
  first = word[0]
  print word[1:] + first + pyg,
```